# Need for looping into DropdownSearch in Flutter

Tags: flutter, loops, dart, dropdown

Please I need help for looping **years**  in this widget DropdownSearch.
I'm using this script, but return with wrong Values.

```
DropdownSearch(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    controller.tahunC.text = value.toString();
                    print(controller.tahunC.text);
                  },
                  showClearButton: true,
                  dropdownSearchDecoration: const InputDecoration(
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.image),
                    labelText: "Tahun",
                    hintText: 'Tahun',
                  ),
                  items: List<String>.generate(
                      (DateTime.now().year).toInt() - 2021,
                      (int index) => '${index + 1}').map(
                    (val) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: val,
                        child: Text(val),
                      );
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                ),
```

Comment: what values are you getting?

Comment: I need 2021, 2022, 2023. But it shows like this 'DropdownMenuItem<String>'